# Does the iPhone 3G/3Gs camera put metadata in its images? (and how do you get it?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, graphics, camera

I've been trying to figure how whether the iPhone (either 3G or 3Gs) camera puts metadata into it's images.  Anecdotally, it appears that it does (e.g., I've seen images posted on the web that included a bunch of metadata), but I can't find reference to it anywhere in the SDK documentation.  So....does anyone have a definitive answer?  Also, if there *is* metadata, how do I get at it?

Comment: Isn't it just normal EXIF metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is metadata.  Check out the [iphone-exif project](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/), which provides you a means to get/set the EXIF tags.  As they note, UIImage will strip out the metadata. iphone-exif works around this.  It requires you to use the UIImageJPEGRepresentation() function to feed the NSData into a specialized scanner class, which they provide.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the API hides that data out of privacy concerns. The data is in the images but you can't get to it using the Apple API.

Comment: How would I get at that data then (for example, if I wanted to parse it myself)?  I think UIImage.CGImage only gives you content data, not the entire thing.